# PHP: convert unicode to readable string

Tags: php

How can i convert this string using php to readable string?

for example:

```
/%d7%a6%d7%95%d7%a8-%d7%a7%d7%a9%d7%a8/
```

this string is in hebrew

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mb_convert_encoding`

```
echo mb_convert_encoding("/%d7%a6%d7%95%d7%a8-%d7%a7%d7%a9%d7%a8/", 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
```

Comment: Hi, @6339 your code convert this to chinese characters and not to hebrew

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
$string = '%u05E1%u05E2';
$string = preg_replace('/%u([0-9A-F]+)/', '&#x$1;', $string);
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: HI @Insane Skulll i tried with my string and this code did not work. can you please check with my string?
/%d7%a6%d7%95%d7%a8-%d7%a7%d7%a9%d7%a8/